# Add click event to open individual picture box image

Tags: vb.net, picturebox, flowlayout

I'm adding images in a picturebox to a flowlayout panel. I'm trying to add a click event so that when the image is clicked on in the flowlayout panel, it will open the original image. My pictures are .jpg. Here's what i got so far but seems like it's not working.

```
For Each pic As FileInfo In New DirectoryInfo("picturepath").GetFiles("file.jpg")
    Dim picture As New PictureBox
    picture .Height = 113
    picture .Width = 145
    picture .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
    picture .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
    picture .Image = Image.FromFile(fi.FullName)

    AddHandler picture.MouseClick, AddressOf pictureBox_MouseClick
    flowlayoutpanel.Controls.Add(picture)
Next

Public Sub pictureBox_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
     ====>>> Not sure what goes here to get the correct path of that image since there could be more than one images.
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you add your `picturePreview_MouseClick` function

Comment: @jonju minor text error.

Comment: First you need to save the name/path of the source file (`fi.FullName`) so you have access to it later.  The filepath is not encoded into the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the "sender" parameter to get a reference to the PictureBox that was clicked:

```
Public Sub pictureBox_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    Dim pb As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
    ' ... now do something with "pb" (and/or "pb.Image") ...
End Sub
```

With a reference to only the PictureBox (as in my example above), you would only have the image itself referenced.  If you want the full path of the file then you'd have to store that information with the PictureBox somehow; using the Tag property is one simple way:

```
Dim picture As New PictureBox
...
picture.Image = Image.FromFile(fi.FullName)
picture.Tag = fi.Fullname
```

Now you can retrieve that filename in the click event and do something with it:

```
Public Sub pictureBox_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    Dim pb As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)

    ' ... now do something with "pb" (and/or "pb.Image") ...
    Dim fileName As String = pb.Tag.ToString()
    Process.Start(fileName)
End Sub
```

Comment: if i use process.start, what would be the default windows photo to use?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: just open the image when clicked on.

Comment: On a side note, when you use Image.FromFile() and "Zoom" like that, even though you are looking at a small "Thumbnail", the ENTIRE image is loaded taking up memory.  Your system will take a hard memory hit if you load up a bunch of larger images this way.  You need to dynamically load the entire image, actually make a smaller thumbnail from it (and display that), then Dispose() of the original large image instance.

Comment: @Idle_Mind umm. i think i need to open the image as a copy and not the original, because if i open it the way i have it, its going to hold the picture in my application therefore if i wanted to open the original image from the document, it will say my app have it open? Anyway around this?

Comment: Yes, don't use `Image.FromFile()`.  Do a search on how to prevent a file lock when opening an image in VB.Net...